# Rigid Body Coin Keeps rolling after landing on Plane

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I have a coin flipping with rigid body applied to both coin and plane. The coin lands fine but keeps rotating endlessly and does not look very real. I have tried the *Deactivate* setting with no success.

Has anyone any idea what the issue may be?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-H0J4f4KGV4)

Comment: Avoid using convex hull. It's rarely accurate. For the plane change it to box and for the coin change it to mesh. The only time you shouldn't be using mesh for active object is if it has a ton of vertices or you are simulating a ton of objects. Always use box if the floor is just a plane.

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Link to file uploaded now. I changed the convex hull to box and mesh but I have the same issues. The coin keeps slowing rotating and moving after it hits the floor, it never comes to a stop.

Comment: Wait why do you have a collision and a rigid body modifier on your coin?
Plus your plane has bounciness set to 100%

Comment: @TheJeran I disagree. Convex hull is the default, and works fine. Mesh shape, however, is terrible IMO, and should not be used unless you are desperate for concave collision. The OP has switched to mesh to avoid convex hull, which is why I mention that.

Comment: I suspect this is because the coin’s mass and size are not set realistically. Also, why do you have gravity at an inaccurate setting?

Comment: I am very new to Blender so I played around with the various settings to try and get the result I need, I'm not sure on what the appropriate settings should be. I changed the gravity to this as it seemed to give the coin the most accurate 'flight' time. But after adjusting these again I am still left with the coin just rotating endlessly and not coming to a stop.

Comment: As @TheLabCat points out, your coin is huge (1kg mass and 2m wide). In addition, it is extremely complex. I suggest you take a few steps back, and set up a simulation of a simplified coin on a plane, and get that running. Take it from there.

Comment: I have to disagree strongly with TheJeran here; mesh collision is terrible, and convex hull is superior whenever you are using a convex shape (and often, even when you aren't.)  A coin should be convex.  However, using cylinder collision ought to be more appropriate even than convex hull.  Mesh collision is slow and unreliable compared to both convex hull and collision primitives.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've recreated the coin a lot smaller and joined each element rather than linking them as parent and applied rigid body again with fewer adjustments and I have it looking a lot better. Thanks for the replies and suggestions !